# XPath expression syntax validation

Tags: java, xml, validation, xpath, syntax

I am currently working on a Java project using XPath and since I am not an XPath expert I need to find a way to validate the syntax of random XPath expressions, without matching them to XML data.

I found many XPath validators on the web and unfortunately all of them require XML data.

My immediate need is to validate the following expression:

```
/cXML/Request/OrderRequest/OrderRequestHeader/Extrinsic/@name[NameOrder]/Name
```

I'd appreciate comments on the validity of this specific one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to validate the syntax but not if the expression is valid within the context of a your xml or xml schema. You can use the [compile(..)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html#compile%28java.lang.String%29) method and it will throw an exception if the xpath is incorrect w.r.t the syntax.

```
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//book[author='Abc']/title/text()");
```

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. So my quest is actually ending here: that's the validator I was looking for, which will tell me whether the syntax is correct, but which unfortunately will never tell me whether the expression actually makes sense, as pointed out by Michael...

Answer (score 3):

"Since you are not an XPath expert", most of the errors you make in your XPath expressions will probably not be syntax errors but semantic errors. Most errors in XPath expressions, sadly, aren't detected as syntax errors or even run-time errors, but simply result in wrong answers. (XPath is quite similar to regular expressions in this regard.)

Your example is a case in point. It's syntactically valid, but will never select anything. That's because it includes the step `@name[NameOrder]`, which selects all "name" attributes that have a NameOrder child element. Attributes never have children, so nothing will satisfy this expression. Saxon will give you a warning, but it's not a syntax error.

So I don't think your approach of doing syntax validation is going to help you much.

Comment: Thanks Michael, that's quite surprising actually: the fact that the XPath standard allows XPath expressions that would never select any data. In this regard, for sure my quest does not have much purpose...