# Validate xpath syntax correctness in php

Tags: php, xml, validation, xpath, syntax

I have a given xpath with no xml document to try and test it against, but I still have to make sure the xpath is correctly formatted.

Two examples are as follows:

CORRECT SYNTAX:
'//BuyerCookie/child/grandchild'

INCORRECT SYNTAX:
"/foo/bar/@baz/@boy"

I need to check whether a correct or an incorrect xpath string has been passed in. Any suggestions?

Basically the exta same questions as this one:

[XPath expression syntax validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729210/xpath-expression-syntax-validation)

But a PHP solution.

Comment: If you do not have a particular XML to test against, then why not test against _any_ well-formed document and look at the response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like if you use DOMXPATH::query($xpath) with your XPath selector to test, it will return FALSE if the XPath is not valid.

So, I would try:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

// this one is good
$str="//a//li/div[@class='foo']";
assert($xpath->query($str) !== false);

// this one is bad
$str="//a/@@bob/uncle";
assert(@$xpath->query($str) === false);
```

See also: https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php

Note that when you run $xpath->query() on a malformed XPath, you will also get PHP Warnings; I put an @ in the last line so you won't see them.

Finally, one thing: The xpath you give as being invalid -- `/foo/bar/@baz/@boy` -- is not, in fact, invalid.

Comment: Thank you @romulusnr this works perfectly! Also thanks for correcting my error on '/foo/bar/@baz/@boy' :)

Comment: I just ran my test and found that in fact /foo/bar/@baz/@boy is an invalid case. I receive an false from the query() return.

Comment: That's interesting. I get:

`$ php -r '$doc=new DOMDocument; $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc); $str="/foo/bar/@baz/@boy"; var_dump($xpath->query($str));'`  

`object(DOMNodeList)#3 (1) {  
  ["length"]=>  
  int(0)  
}`  

I wonder if it's a version issue. I'm using PHP 5.3.26 (yes, I know, it's a work thing).

Comment: I'm using PHP 5.5.9, I wonder if it is a version issue... but by xpath rules, '/foo/bar/@baz/@boy' doesn't make much sense regardless to version... attributes are I believe a leaf node, which means no more digging into them with a new /@ at least from my understanding...

Comment: All versions since 5.0.0 seem to accept it: https://3v4l.org/O4U5J